# A matrix product bounded by one matrix norm implies other matrix norm is bounded by one

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are square matrices and that
$$ \|AB\|_F \leq \|A\|_F. $$
Also suppose that the range of $B$ is *not* in the kernel of $A$.  (Best case scenario, suppose $A$ and $B$ are both nonsingular.)
Is it necessarily true that
$$ \|B\|_F \leq 1 ?$$
My attempts at both proving (via norm definitions and contradiction) and finding counterexamples (numerically) have been fruitless.

Comment: Consider the case that the kernel of $A$ contains the range of $B$. For example, the extreme case $A=0$.

Comment: Gonna update the question, hold on...

Comment: Answer for the future: Yes, it is true when all the cases in which it is not true are excluded.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Lol, chill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]
Try 
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0& 1/10^6\cr}, B = \pmatrix{1/2 & 0\cr 0& 1000}$$

Comment: Nice. I've updated the question to rule out this situation.

Comment: And I've updated the answer to rule it back in.

Comment: Thanks for rising to the challenge.